React get link from folder not in folder public
I'm learning React so I don't know how to get the file link, I use:
import src from "~/mock/VBQPPL/06-bct.signed.pdf";

then the result :

/static/media/06-bct.signed.35d5ab2496077c2fd75f.pdf

I want to get this link to make the href for the a tag, but without using import, is there any way?
I tried before:
const item = vbqppl.find((item) => item.number === number);
const fileUrl = `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/mock/VBQPPL/${item.file}`;
const fileUrl = require(`~/mock/VBQPPL/06-bct.signed.pdf`);

and the second line gives an error, and the first line gives the following link but this link is not correct:

/mock/VBQPPL/06-bct.signed.pdf

My folder structure:
- **public**
  - index.html
- **src**
  - **assets**
      - **images**
        - logo.png
        - background.jpg
      - **styles**
        - main.css
        - reset.css
  - **features**
    - **VBQPPL**
      - Detail.jsx
      - List.jsx
      - ...
  - **components**
    - Header.jsx
    - Footer.jsx
    - ...
  - **pages**
    - Home.jsx
    - About.jsx
    - Contact.jsx

  - **mock**
    - **VBQPPL**
        - *.pdf
- App.js
- index.js
- index.css

